# the How to Read MultiFrame DICOM Image

Tags: c#-2.0, dicom

I am able to read the first frame but how will I read the other frames? There are 60 frames in a file.

Answer (score 5):

For uncompressed images, the frames are stored in one continuous blob. For compressed images, the first data item (FFFE,E000) has a list of 4-byte offsets to the start of each frame.

For example, a 200x200x16-bit uncompressed frame takes 80000 bytes. If your file has 50 frames, it will have 80K x 50 = 4MB of image data. The frames are stacked together in order so frame N will be at offset N x 80K bytes.

For compressed frames the start of the data item contains a list of 4 byte integers with absolute offsets into the file for each frame. Each frame's compressed data length is gotten from the data item pointed to by the list.

Comment: Thanks For your reply can you please provide any technical help to read second frame and so on.

Comment: If my current answer doesn't get you going, then you need to share your code so that I can see where to help you.